# Facebook like button straight from facebook doesn't work in FF, chrome, and safari

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, facebook-like, admin

So I've got a really weird one.

I am trying to figure out whats wrong with what must be an admin on facebook issue.

Basically the simple like button does not display except in IE

It doesn't even show on the facebook create the like button if you are in Fire Fox, Chrome, or Safari.
 For example try to create a button in any browser other than IE, and you won't get your sample if you input the company name.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Works fine with any other facebook page except for my clients site.
Try nordtrom or Ferrari works fine.

Has anybody ever come across this issue?
 This must be a setting in Facebook blocking it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested the issue was with the restrictions on country. Removed the restrictions. Works like a charm.

Comment: To complete the answer, if age or country restrictions are enabled, facebook plugin will not show for people, not signed in facebook and people who does not satisfy the restrictions.

Above is also true for pages that are set to unpubished.

Also if you are newbie like me and you don't know what permissions we are talking about. It is permissions of Facebook Page or whatsoever 'like button' you are trying to setup. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I think because your page is not accessible . If i click on https://www.facebook.com/westseattlecoins

i am redirected to my home page of facebook . If i try ferrari i go to the page of Ferrari . Facebook need to see your page for reading it .

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it lead me to look in the proper location.